# Esper: Throw event when a value exceeds a threshold

Tags: java, complex-event-processing, esper

I'm new to Esper and I try to implement an alert system. I need to throw an Event when an item value is exceeding a threshold.
For instance, for a Car, I want to get an Event when the property tank exceeds value 40 and another Event when this value gets back under 40.

I've tried a lot of functionnality of Esper but nothing works.

I wanted to do something like that but it does not work fine:

```
insert into AlertEvt select b from pattern[t=Car while (t.tank > 90) -> b=AlertEvt(type=t.tank, machineName=t.module)]
```

Hope somebody can help me.

Answer (score 0):

This one alerts when the value exceeds 40:

```
select * from Event(value > 40)
```

This one alerts when the value falls below 40 after once exceeding 40:

```
select * from pattern[Event(value > 40) -> Event(value < 40)]
```

Since you didn't state how often you want to alert (once, every time?), and when not to alert (suppress while over 40 or not?), I didn't add any repetition or any suppression. The solution patterns page is very helpful.  I have a few links below that may help you address the requirements that you didn't say.

http://espertech.com/esper/solution_patterns.php#semantic-window-0

http://espertech.com/esper/solution_patterns.php#semantic-window-1

http://espertech.com/esper/solution_patterns.php#semantic-window-2

Comment: Thanks, it's usefull. Your request throws the "end alert". I'm trying to throw one event when alert begins, and one event when it ends. But while value is upper threshold, I don't want to throw many alerts. Maybe with esper contexts.

Comment: To get the first event  only try "context xyz select * from Event#firstevent". Otherwise context is the way to go.